# Creating a loop in Javascript based on php variable

Tags: javascript

Let us say I have the following script, calculating a sum.

Here is the code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function updatesum() {

    line1 = ((document.form.price_1.value -0) * (document.form.number_1.value -0));

    line2 = ((document.form.price_2.value -0) * (document.form.number_2.value -0));

    line3 = ((document.form.price_3.value -0) * (document.form.number_3.value -0));

    line4 = ((document.form.price_4.value -0) * (document.form.number_4.value -0));

    line5 = ((document.form.price_5.value -0) * (document.form.number_5.value -0));

    document.form.sum.value = line1 + line2 + line3 + line4 + line5;

    }
    </script>

    </head>        
    <body>

    <?php

$tR = 1;
$maxlines = 5;

echo '<form name="form" method="post" action="action.php">';
echo '<table><tbody>';

while($tR <= $maxlines)
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td width="1"><input name="price_' . $tR . '" onChange="updatesum();"         type="text"></td>';
echo '<td width="1"> x </td>';
echo '<td width="1"><input name="number_' . $tR . '" onChange="updatesum();"         type="text" value="1"></td>';
echo '</tr>';
++$tR;
}
echo '</tbody></table>';

echo 'Total: <input name="sum" value="0" type="text" readonly="readonly">';
echo '<button type="submit" name="Submit" style="display: hidden;">Submit</button>';
echo '</form>';

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And that's fine... But now i change the variable $maxlines from 5 to 500...
How do I adjust the Javascript, without having to write something like:

```
function updatesum() {

line1 = ((document.form.price_1.value -0) * (document.form.number_1.value -0));

line2 = ((document.form.price_2.value -0) * (document.form.number_2.value -0));

line3 = ((document.form.price_3.value -0) * (document.form.number_3.value -0));

line4 = ((document.form.price_4.value -0) * (document.form.number_4.value -0));

line5 = ((document.form.price_5.value -0) * (document.form.number_5.value -0));

line6 = ((document.form.price_6.value -0) * (document.form.number_6.value -0));

  .......................

line500 = ((document.form.price_500.value -0) * (document.form.number_500.value -0));

document.form.sum.value = line1 + line2 + line3 + line4 + line5 + line6 ........... + line500;

}
```

Comment: Use a loop??? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: You want to do a loop in php or javascript?

Comment: You could always loop in Javascript getting the elements.

Comment: @EibergDK: I've added a detailed answer, explaining some improvements to your code. Hope you are still reading, I guess it took me a while to write it while other answers has popped up, but I hope I included some information that will be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to go through all the fields:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function updatesum() {
            var prices = document.getElementsByName('price');
            var numbers = document.getElementsByName('number');
            var sum = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
                sum += prices[i].value * numbers[i].value;
            }
            document.form.sum.value = sum;
        }
        </script>
    </head>        
    <body>
        <?php
            $tR = 1;
            $maxlines = 50;

            echo '<form name="form" method="post" action="action.php">';
            echo '<table><tbody>';

            while($tR <= $maxlines)
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td width="1"><input name="price" onChange="updatesum();"         type="text"></td>';
                echo '<td width="1"> x </td>';
                echo '<td width="1"><input name="number" onChange="updatesum();"         type="text" value="1"></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                ++$tR;
            }
            echo '</tbody></table>';

            echo 'Total: <input name="sum" value="0" type="text" readonly="readonly">';
            echo '<button type="submit" name="Submit" style="display: hidden;">Submit</button>';
            echo '</form>';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily transfer php variables to javascript like this

```
<script>
var maxlines = <?php echo $maxLines?>;
</script>
```

You now have a javascript variable maxlines equal to your php variable 
Also, remember if you are transferring a string to put it in quotations

```
<script>
var myString = '<?php echo $myString?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The short version would be to update the script and have a loop there that does all this.

**BUT** (and a huge but that is)

There are a few things you can improve in your script, other than the solution itself.
You can try a different approach to your issue:

- You don't have to bind a function to each input change element separately, and using `onchange` attributes in HTML is a little outdated method.
- You don't have to define each line. You can sum them all up using JavaScript, without knowing how many of them you have.
- I would rename your `input` elements `name` attribute into something you could work with in PHP, without knowing its size beforehand. For example, if you change the name of the attributes to `name="price[]"` and `name="number[]"`, your values will magically be sent to your PHP script as `$_POST["price"]` and `$_POST["number"]`. From there, you can play with it dynammicaly.

And now to some real code:

By building the HTML as I've explained, you will end up with something following this idea:

```
<form name="form">
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="1" /><input type="text" name="number[]" value="10" /><br />
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="2" /><input type="text" name="number[]" value="20" /><br />
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="3" /><input type="text" name="number[]" value="30" /><br />
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="4" /><input type="text" name="number[]" value="40" /><br />
<br /><input type="text" name="sum" value="0" id="sum" />
</form>
```

And then, following the event binding techniques I suggested, your JavaScript will be simplified to something like this:

```
function updateSum() {
    var prices = document.getElementsByName("price[]");
    var numbers = document.getElementsByName("number[]");
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < prices.length; i++) {
         sum += prices[i].value * numbers[i].value;
    }

    document.getElementById("sum").value = sum;
} 

var prices = document.getElementsByName("price[]");
var numbers = document.getElementsByName("number[]");
for (var i=0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    prices[i].addEventListener('change', updateSum, false);
    numbers[i].addEventListener('change', updateSum, false);
}
```

I've created a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/nXqgW/2/) showing this code in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code like that:

```
<script>
function updatesum() {
    <?php $lines = array() ?>
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) : ?>
        line<?= $i ?> = ((document.form.price_<?= $i ?>.value -0) * (document.form.number_<?= $i ?>.value -0));
        <?php $lines[] = 'line' . $i;
    <?php endfor; ?>
    document.form.sum.value = <?= implode(' + ', $lines);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this approach is quite straight forward. I would offer to use jQuery for this task, it's much better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to output the javascript lines with PHP, so in PHP where you have your maxlines variables you can do a loop like;

```
<script>
    ...
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < $maxlines; $i++) {
        //Output javascript line
        ?>

        line<?php echo $i; ?> = ((document.form.price_<?php echo $i; ?>.value -0) * (document.form.number_<?php echo $i; ?>.value -0));
    <?php
    } ?>

    document.form.sum.value = 0 <?php for($int i = 0; $i < $maxlines; $i++) {
        echo '+ line' . $i;
    } ?>
</script>
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should work.